# Does Cyclone Strike have some kind of hidden stun?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The description for [Cyclone Strike](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/cyclone-strike) reads:

> Pull all enemies within 24 yards towards you, followed by a furious
>   blast of energy that deals 100% weapon damage as Holy.

I use this skill constantly on my Monk tank, and I've noticed anytime I use this skill, enemies stop attacking for a second to re-orient themselves. The pause is so noticeable that I've started using this skill when I'm desperate, just to stop attacks for a second so I can regen hp and wait for cooldowns.

If I have the spirit for it, I can even chain together multiple Cyclone Strikes to prevent taking almost any damage at all for a few seconds since the skill has no cooldown and I use the Eye of the Storm rune to reduce the cost of this skill

Am I just imaging things, or is there really some kind of hidden stun involved in Cyclone Strike?

Comment: I noticed something similar with Wall of Zombies.

Comment: I have found that a number of abilities "stagger" enemies but don't know if it is inherent to the ability or based on damage dealt (or both).

Comment: Isn't it just the pull that stops them? Together with the fact that they need to turn. It would probably stop them for doing something for 0.5-1sec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have noticed a similar effect. A combo that I highly enjoy is to pull everyone in with Cyclone Strike and knock them all back out again with Lashing Tail kick.

Is it a stun as far as game mechanics are concerned? No. Technically the enemies are not incapacitated. What it does do, is reset their "swing timer" as they have been moved and interrupted by the Cyclone Strike.

Comment: That's my favourite combo, too. Good times.

Comment: I prefer to follow with Wave of Light, Explosive Light style.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Cyclone Strike works similar to a knockback effect, except pulling towards you. I did a little testing and there's a similar stun effect for different knockback abilities. Fists of Thunder's knockback resulted in a small stun effect (after landing), while Lashing Tail Kick resulted in a longer stun effect.